# How to use multiple functions based on a condition using lapply

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I have a question regarding using multiple functions in lapply using a condition. 
Here is the data frame

```
Data <- data.frame(c(1:6),c(7:12), c(1,0,1,0,1,1), 0)
colnames(Data) <- c("a","b","c","d")
```

I want an out put applied to each row based on a condition , like in this case if col c is 1, i want to use a min function and if col c is 0 I want to use a max function.

I tried this

```
Output <- lapply(Data$d, if(Data$c == 1){min(Data$b - Data$c, Data$a)} else 
{max(Data$b - Data$c, Data$a)})
```

but the condition is not based on a single cell but it rather takes the whole column, how do I get this condition for the cell in that particular row?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can vectorize with `pmin/pmax` and using `ifelse` instead of `if/else`

```
with(Data, ifelse(c == 1, pmin(b - c, a), pmax(b, a)))
```

Note that for the "no" expression, we don't need `b-c` as 'c' is 0 for the column

Comment: Okay, thanks. So If i write my own function how do I vectorize it? I have written a custom ceiling function which I want to use instead of pmin and pmax. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Kou `pmin/pmax` is already vectorized.  If you want to vectorize your function, try `Vectorize(yourfun)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with R, but these situations usually warrant a 'switch'. When there's one condition to evaluate, and 2 or more outcomes, a switch is usually a clear way to do things.

Maybe:

```
Output <- switch(Data$c, 
1 = min(Data$b - Data$c, Data$a),
0 = max(Data$b - Data$c, Data$a))
```

I like switches because it makes very clear what's going on. Plus, if you need to add a 'default' or more options, it's very easy.

I can't promise that the code there will work, because I don't know R, but maybe that's a push in the right direction? :)